# Looking to improve Android ViewPager UI performance

Tags: performance, android-viewpager, android-tablelayout

My Android app uses a `ViewPager` to display a list of items on each page. Each list row is made up of a `TableLayout`, which in turns has three `TableRows` each with a few `TextViews` and one with an `ImageView`.

Things work great, but as more pages (and therefore lists) are added, the UI bogs down, especially when paging horizontally (far less during the vertical list scroll). I'm looking for how I might be able to improve the UI performance.

Using Hierarchy View, only the `ViewPager` itsef shows high Layout and Draw times (i.e., red stop light icon) with 10 pages and 4-20 list items (rows) on each page. The layout seems shallow already, but I wonder if things can be improved even more.

Some pseudo code to give an idea of the layout structure:

**Each list row uses a TableLayout structured like this:**

```
<TableLayout>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView/ >
        <TextView/ >
        <TextView/ >
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <ImageView/>
        <TextView/ >
        <TextView/ >
        <TextView/ >
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView/ >
        <TextView/ >
        <TextView/ >
    </TableRow> 

    <TableRow>
        <TextView/ >
        <TextView/ >
    </TableRow> 

    <TableRow >     
        <TextView/ >
        <TextView/ >
        <TextView/ >
        <TextView/ >
    </TableRow>     
</TableLayout>
```

The main activity's layout inflates the support `ViewPager`. I use `ListFragment` on each `ViewPager` page, so when a new page is created, the `ListFragment` code inflates the `ListView` layout, which in turn inflates the `TableLayout` shown above.

Specific question I have:

- Should I replace the `TableLayout` with a `RelativeLayout` and attempt to get rid of one depth layer? Since I display my `TextViews` in five rows, each having 2-4 fields with varying spacing, I suspect that might get tricky. But even if I could accomplish it, would it buy me anything, given that Hierarchy View shows nothing but "green light" icons for each entire table layout
- I'm using `FragmentPagerAdapter`. Is it plain crazy to have up to 10 pages in memory using this? I know the recommendations are not more than 3-4 pages when using this (or something like that). I've tried the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, but ended up spending too much time/resources/battery to constantly retrieve data from the internet while paging. (I know, maybe I need to cache it...). I need the ability to retain the views and have been playing with the `setOffScreenPageLimit` as well, setting it to 10 so that all views are retained in memory.

Any advice is appreciated as I'm still relatively new to Android, thanks.

Comment: Have you solved this problem?